# Where are we commanded to light candles Fri night?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sources-mekorot, blessing, candle-lighting

The bracha for lighting candles Friday night is "who has sanctified us with his commandments and commanded us to light the lamp of Shabbat." What is the source for the commandment? While we are on this topic, where is the source for the commandment to light candles on yontif?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/767153/jewish/Where-Does-the-Torah-Say-to-Light-Shabbat-Candles.htm. http://www.bknw.org/uploads/5/9/9/5/5995719/shabbos_candles_1.pdf